# JAX-WS exception handling - best way

Tags: exception, jax-ws

I'm a bit confused... 
I have a webapp exposing soap webservices. 
Now I need my ws's clients to get exception my ws methods are generating (custom exceptions and generic exceptions like Hibernate Exception and so on).
I read a lot but I can't figure out a good solution for... can you please indicate me the best way for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly what you are wanting to know here. You can define custom `Exception` classes and annotate them as `@WebFault` and then throw those back to the client. I generally create a base exception class (annotated with `@WebFault`) then have all of my other custom exceptions extend from that class. If you can clarify your question a bit perhaps we can get you a better answer. :)

Comment: Yes I know, I was all excepts clear with my question! So thanks a lot for your reply. Here it's, `@webfault` is one of my doubts... It works the same for me if my custom exception class is annotated or not with`@webfault` . What does it do? Another question... Is this article obsolete? (http://io.typepad.com/eben_hewitt_on_java/2009/07/using-soap-faults-and-exceptions-in-java-jaxws-web-services.html) I can't figure the need of what described in it! @Michael

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if I really have a good answer for what you have different between applying the @WebFault annotation or not. I know I opted to add it to mine, but it's been about four years since I did that work. So, I can't remember exactly the reason... I thought I had to in order to make it work correctly. What are you using to generate your client? (JAX-WS RI, Apache CXF, etc?) I was using JAX-WS RI

Comment: Ok, no problem! Let's see if someone can help us about `@webfault`annotation. I'm using Apache CXF.